# AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, attributes

I am new to Python. I have started to use pyfolio library and when I typed the following code

```
pf.create_returns_tear_sheet(data['New_Adjusted_Returns'],benchmark_rets=None)
```

An error named occurred as follow:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

data['New_Adjusted_Returns'] consists of the following data:

```
Date
2020-02-14   -0.004500
2020-02-17   -0.022107
2020-02-18   -0.000029
2020-02-19   -0.000800
2020-02-20   -0.017102
2020-02-21   -0.000028
2020-02-24    0.014400
2020-02-25    0.007900
2020-02-26   -0.001000
2020-02-27   -0.000517
2020-02-28   -0.000029


Would someone be able to help me on this issue? Thank you very much.
```

Comment: The `,benchmark_rets=None` is superfluous, as this is the default value for that named parameter. Apparently, the data you're passing in to `.create_returns_tear_sheet()` is not in the expected format and a pandas datetime was expected instead of a numpy 64-bit integer. You've provided a print out of the data after loading, but how do you load it and from what?

Comment: I extracted the date index and column values from the dataframe, so I assume it should not be in numpy. I checked the data, the date is datetime object and the values are float 64. I really don't know why the error occurred like that..

Comment: What is the type of `data`, how did you construct it and where did the data come from?

Comment: The type of data is float64. I construct them by making use of data from the imported csv file using pandas library. The data could be acquired here:https://hk.investing.com/indices/sse-50-futures-historical-data

Comment: So, the type of the `data` variable is a `pandas.DataFrame`? The URL you linked provides no easy way for an English speaker to obtain a .csv - please provide some sample data in your question, as well as an example of the code you use to read it.

Comment: Yes, the type of the data variable is a pandas.Dataframe and the data in this dataframe are float64. I apologize for the wrong version provided. You may easily refer to this link for the data sample: https://www.investing.com/indices/sse-50-futures-historical-data

Comment: The solution in this answer solved the problem for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418898/pyfolio-attributeerror-numpy-int64-object-has-no-attribute-to-pydatetime. An alternative solution is to use this package instead: https://pypi.org/project/QuantStats/

Answer (score 11):

fixed this by changing line 893 in file timeseries.py

```
valley = underwater.index[np.argmin(underwater)] # end of the period
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anoop. I solved my problem as well

Answer (score 2):

I met the same question in my huawei laptop,but it's ok in my Surface.
I solved this problem by following corrections.

On line 894, replace

```
valley = np.argmin(underwater)
```

with

```
valley=underwater.index[np.argmin(underwater)]
```

On line 897, replace

```
peak=valley = np.argmin(underwater)
```

with

```
temp1=underwater[:valley][underwater[:valley] == 0].dropna(axis=0,how='any')
peak = temp1.index[-1]
```

On line 901, replace

```
recovery=underwater[valley:][underwater[valley:] == 0]
```

with

```
temp2=underwater[valley:][underwater[valley:] == 0].dropna(axis=0,how='any')
    recovery = temp2.index[0]
```

#####################

And if there are still errors about `to_pydatetime` after applying above solutions, you can replace `.to_pydatetime().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` with `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` on lines 1010, 1013, and 1018.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message retrieve the error code file, for example:

`!cat /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyfolio/timeseries.py`

Copy the output to notepade++, and replace line 1005, 1008, and 1015 expressions involving *.to_pydatetime() by

```
pd.to_datetime(peak)
pd.to_datetime(valley
pd.to_datetime(recovery)
```

respectively.

Copy the revised contents to a cell beginning with

`%%writefile /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyfolio/timeseries.py`

and execute it to overwrite the original file.

Then execute the following before rerun the pf.create_full_tear_sheet(data) that for example bring about this error:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I pip installed pyfolio and was getting the same error.

After some digging I found this function :

```
def get_max_drawdown_underwater(underwater):
   ...
```

And that the valley variable was ill-defined resulting in the returned variable being of type nump.int64 and not timestamp as stated in the function description.

```
vallay = underwater.index[np.argmin(underwater)] # np.argmin(underwater)
```

In white is what I have written and commented out is what I got from the pip install.

All the metrics and graphs appear now:

[image: figure output]

Comment: Hi @Mandlenkosi Ngcobo. Please don't post picture of code. Instead use the code block because it is easy to copy and past. And the formatting is easyier for you, too.