# KeyError in PyFolio

Tags: python

I'm trying to use PyFolio to display some stats.  Currently I'm feeding it a Series, but I've also tried this with a DataFrame.  My `simple_returns` Series looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
DatetimeIndex: 883 entries, 2020-01-02 to 2022-06-02
Series name: PnL
Non-Null Count  Dtype  
--------------  -----  
883 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 13.8 KB
None

Date
2020-01-02    0.001316
2020-01-03    0.001019
2020-01-04    0.000000
2020-01-05    0.000000
2020-01-06    0.000000
...
```

`pf.plot_drawdown_underwater(simple_returns, figsize=[14,4])` works.

`pf.create_simple_tear_sheet(simple_returns, benchmark_rets=None)` produces a `KeyError: 'date'`.
Similar error with a DataFrame.

- I don't understand the KeyError.  It's not complaining about 'Date' vs 'date', is it?  I tried renaming the column but couldn't figure out how to rename the index.
- I have no idea why it's trying to read from Yahoo or Google, since I told it not to use a benchmark.

```
c:\Miniforge\envs\zipline\lib\site-packages\empyrical\utils.py:440: UserWarning: Yahoo Finance read failed: 'date', falling back to Google
  warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Miniforge\envs\zipline\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File c:\Miniforge\envs\zipline\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File c:\Miniforge\envs\zipline\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'date'
```

Also, `pf.show_worst_drawdown_periods(simple_returns)` produces `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'` in `gen_drawdown_table`.

- I don't understand why it's complaining about `numpy.int64` -- my Series is `float64`.

```
File c:\Miniforge\envs\zipline\lib\site-packages\pyfolio\timeseries.py:999, in gen_drawdown_table(returns, top)
    994     df_drawdowns.loc[i, 'Duration'] = len(pd.date_range(peak,
    995                                                         recovery,
    996                                                         freq='B'))
    997 df_drawdowns.loc[i, 'Peak date'] = (peak.to_pydatetime()
    998                                     .strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
--> 999 df_drawdowns.loc[i, 'Valley date'] = (valley.to_pydatetime()
   1000                                       .strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
   1001 if isinstance(recovery, float):
   1002     df_drawdowns.loc[i, 'Recovery date'] = recovery

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

An answer here suggested re-installing from github, but I'm wondering if that's still the right answer 2.5 yrs later.  Other places suggest downgrading empyrical or other packages, but again that was years-old advice.

[Pyfolio - AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418898/pyfolio-attributeerror-numpy-int64-object-has-no-attribute-to-pydatetime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyfolio - AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to\_pydatetime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418898/pyfolio-attributeerror-numpy-int64-object-has-no-attribute-to-pydatetime)

Comment: I'm nervous about uninstalling with conda and then re-installing with pip, but hopefully it won't mess anything up.  So I conda-uninstalled pyfolio, and pip-installed it from the git path.  I got an error:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Miniforge\envs\zipline\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 553, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored

Hard to believe it can work well after that ...